# Why does the child component mutation my variable in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mutation-observers

I'm trying to find a way to share a variable between my components in Angular. My variable that I pass to my child components are interchangeable between their child components. I used service for this, but still could not solve the problem. I am sharing a demo by simplifying my operations using BehaviorSubject.

**demo** : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6usdww?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

My problem is:
i am sending variables from my app.component.ts component to hello and hello-a components. i am mutating variable in hello component. However, just before that I point the first version to a service. however, the changed status is forwarded.

**hello.component**

```
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() colDef: any[];

  col: any[];
  constructor(private columnDefService: ColumnDefService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let colDefFirst = Object.assign([], this.colDef);
    this.columnDefService.setFirstColDef(colDefFirst);
    this.setColumnDef(this.colDef);
  }

  setColumnDef(colDef: any[]): void {
    let rC: any = Object.assign([], colDef);
    rC[0].hide = true;
    this.columnDefService.setColDef([].concat(rC));
    this.columnDefService.colDef$.subscribe((colDef: any) => {
      this.col = colDef;
    });
  }
}
```

**hello-a.component**

```
export class HelloAComponent {
  @Input() colDef: any[];

  firstColDef: any[] = [];
  constructor(private ColumnDefService: ColumnDefService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ColumnDefService.firstColDef$.subscribe((firstColDef: any) => {
        console.log('firstColDef', firstColDef);
        this.firstColDef = firstColDef;
      });
  }
}
```

**coldef.service**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ColumnDefService {
  private colDefSource = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  private firstColDefSource = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  colDef$ = this.colDefSource.asObservable();
  firstColDef$ = this.firstColDefSource.asObservable();

  setColDef(colDef: any) {
    this.colDefSource.next(colDef);
  }

  setFirstColDef(colDef: any) {
    this.firstColDefSource.next(colDef);
  }


}
```

this is what i want to do:
storing my variable in a component for future use. i want to continuously change my variable on demand in my other component.

thanks for your advice

Comment: I don't understand your question, tbh. But it looks like you are trying to clone an array of objects via `Object.assign`, which gives a _shallow_ copy. If you wan't a "full" clone you will need a _deep_ clone (e.g. via `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo))`. [Minimal adapted stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pkdd5b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you very much, i solved my problem. i can't believe i missed this